# TCP connections stuck with CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I need your help guys in order to fix issue with non closing TCP connection.

Basically it works fine but after a few minutes it stucks with connection in CLOSE_WAIT state.

[image]

The logic of the code:

The code accepts first packet and parse it and after that it sends the CRC back to the client. If the CRC valid then client sends the main packet to the server and repeat it. Once if there are no packets then client close connection but sometimes it does not. In this case server (code below) close connection after 1 minute of the communications.

I assume it should correspond to https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Product-Articles/TCP-states-explained/ta-p/78462 as well

Here is C# code

```
void TCPListenerServer(object obj) {
  CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken) obj;
  if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
    isDisposed = true;
    if (listener != null) {
      listener.Stop();
    }

    return;
  } else {
    try {
      isDisposed = false;

      try {
        var validIP = IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.ServerIP);
        listener = new TcpListener(validIP, Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPort);
        listener.Start();

        while (isDisposed == false || token.IsCancellationRequested == false) {
          if (token.IsCancellationRequested || isDisposed) {
            break;
          } else {

            if (!listener.Pending()) {
              Thread.Sleep(50);
              continue;
            }

            listener.Server.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
            listener.Server.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);

            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            var arrThread = new ThreadParams() {
              Client = client, Token = m_Cts.Token
            };
            var t = new Thread(ProcessClientRequests) {
              IsBackground = true,
                Name = "ClientConnectionThread",
            };
            clientThreads.Add(t);

            t.Start((object) arrThread);
          }
        }
      } catch (SocketException ex) {
        if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted) {}
      } catch (Exception ex) {} finally {
        if (listener != null) {
          listener.Server.Close();
          listener.Stop();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
  }
}


    private void ProcessClientRequests(object argument) {
      
      TcpClient client = ((ThreadParams) argument).Client;
      CancellationToken token = ((ThreadParams) argument).Token;
      client.SendTimeout = 10000;
      client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
      client.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);
    
      var bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      var isFirstPacket = true;
      var startTime = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    
      try { 
    
        using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
          do {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
          } while (!stream.DataAvailable);
    
          while ((client != null && client.Connected) && stream != null && stream.CanRead && (endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes < 1) {
            if (client == null) {
              break;
            }
    
            do {
              if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                return;
              }
    
              if (client == null) {
                break;
              }
    
              endTime = DateTime.Now;
    
              int streamReadBytes = 0;
              streamReadBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    
              if (streamReadBytes == 0) {
                if (client != null) {
                  client.Close();
                }
                break;
              }
    
              if (buffer[0] == (byte) GalileoskyPacketHeaderEnums.FirstPacket || buffer[0] == (byte) GalileoskyPacketHeaderEnums.MainPacket) {
    
                var parserGalileosky = new Galileosky();
    
                var packetResult = parserGalileosky.ParsePacket(buffer, isFirstPacket);
                if (packetResult == null) {
                  if (client != null) {
                    client.Close();
                    client = null;
                  }
    
                  break;
                }
    
                if (packetResult.Errors.Any()) {
                  if (client != null) {
                    client.Close();
                    client = null;
                  }
                } else {
                  var imei = packetResult.Packet.IMEI;
    
                  if (isFirstPacket) {
                    isFirstPacket = false;
    
                    if (stream.CanWrite == true && packetResult.Packet.IsCrc) {
                      var answerPacket = packetResult.Packet.GetConfirmPacket();
                      stream.Write(answerPacket.Ready);
                    } else {
                      if (client != null) {
                        client.Close();
                        client = null;
                      }
                    }
                  } else // The Main Packet processing
                  {
                    // ... Some code to send the main packet to the app queue

                    if (stream.CanWrite == true && !packetResult.Errors.Any() && packetResult.Packet.IsCrc) {
                      var answerPacket = packetResult.Packet.GetConfirmPacket();
                      stream.Write(answerPacket.Ready);
                    }
    
                    if (packetResult.Packet.IsExtraData == false) {
                      if (client != null) {
                        client.Close();
                        client = null;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
    
                  }
                }
              } else {
                if (client != null) {
                  client.Close();
                  client = null;
                }
              }
              if ((endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes > 1) {
                if (client != null) {
                  client.Close();
                  client = null;
                  break;
                }
              }
    
            }
            while ((client != null && client.Connected) && stream != null && stream.CanRead && stream.DataAvailable && (endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes < 1);
          }
        }
    
        if (client != null) {
          client.Close();
          client = null;
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {} finally {
        if (client != null) {
          client.Close();
          client = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try calling `.ShutDown()` before calling `.Close()`;

Comment: @JohanP Well... I have tried it in different scenarios but it does not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could'n find a way to solve problem to close connection within my code.

But I added a `timer` that close connection and it works just awesome!

```
private void ProcessClientRequests(object argument) 

 // ...  The same code of my quetion

 Timer timerCloseConn = new(new TimerCallback((e) =>
                            {

                                if (stream != null)
                                {
                                    stream.Close();
                                    stream.Dispose();
                                }
                                if (client != null)
                                {

                                    if (client.Client.Connected)
                                    {
                                        client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                                    }

                                    client.Close();
                                    client.Dispose();
                                    client = null;
                                }

                                Logger.Info("The connection has been closed by 
 timer's rule!");
                            }), null, 60000, Timeout.Infinite);

  // ... The same code of my quetion
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if your code is correct, you can hit the "2 generals" problem. There is no perfect algorithm for two parties to agree that a connection is closed, when there may be packet loss.

Gracefully closing a TCP stream requires both parties to shutdown sending, read data up to EOF, then close. I believe that you'll see a socket in CLOSE_WAIT, if one party has shutdown the connection, but the other has not. It looks like you have set your sockets to [linger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.lingerstate?view=net-5.0). In which case the operating system will take over the lifetime of the socket for you.

If your socket is not set to linger, then closing the socket early will cause data that you think you've sent to be lost.

I should also point out that your code is drastically over complicated, with error handling repeated everywhere. It looks like it was probably written before C# introduced async / await.

It also seems that you are assuming that one read operation equates to one data packet. But this is a TCP stream. The OS is allowed to fragment and recombine data that was written from one end, into any number of data reads at the other.

I'd suggest you search the internet for an example that uses `.AcceptTcpClientAsync`, `.ReadAsync`, `.WriteAsync` etc.